# C# Asp.net application converting into smart quotes

Tags: asp.net

publish news to the public website we often copy and paste from documents received from ISIS (public relations company, see associated incident for example). If we copy and paste directly from the attached without editing we end up with strange characters. Usually we find problems with punctuation marks, i.e. hyphens, quotation marks, brackets etc. Each time we publish a news item we need to go through and clean up all these odd characters. Reading around this subject a little I think these problems are being caused by the character set used on the intranet not recognising some of the formatting on the data being pasted.
Can you guide how to approach this as I am very new to the technology . Just a basic idea how to start this . please much appreciate it .

Comment: Can you provide little more info. Are you pasting data in a HTML Editor? and Do you want to maintain the format?

Comment: The Application is ASP.net web forms internal application . It has a functionality to upload news items by copying and pasting . when I copy and paste , it converts few characters into special characters .Microsoft Visual studio 2008 . I am not using html editor . Yes , it would be good to maintain the format .

Comment: It has a functionality to upload news items by copying and pasting? For this what is the control used? Is it a RichText or some kind of editor or uploading as a file?

Comment: Yes, It has a table and text area to enter data in various fields as title and summary and then this data enterd gets published on to internal website .Its Rich Text data  It uses JavaScript to submit the document .

Comment: VS 2008?? Why would anyone use that?? Try migrating to VS 2015. It has so many bug fixes and produces perfect code. And with regards to your question, it has no relation to asp.net. Try searching for regex in Javascript.

Comment: @Ritu : Ok give a try of this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n9PNs/) sample. Copy paste the data that you are having issues. If its what you are looking use it.

Comment: Thanks Thennarasan , I somehow can't run it . Don't know why .

Comment: Access Denied (content_filter_denied) 

  
 Your request was denied because of its content categorization: "Technology/Internet;Office/Business Applications"   
  

 For assistance, contact your network support team.

Your request was categorized by Blue Coat Web Filter as 'Technology/Internet;Office/Business Applications'. 
If you wish to question or dispute this result, please click here.

Comment: Experts Help please!

Comment: It seems your network administrator has blocked those website in firewall. I will post it the code. I will add the code as a answer.

Answer (score 0):

HTML code:

```
<textarea></textarea>
 <button>remove</button>
```

JavaScript code

```
$("button").click(function() {
$("textarea").val(
$("textarea").val().replace(/[^\u0000-\u007E]/g, ""));
$("textarea").focus()[0].select();
});
```

Add a CSS for the textarea to have width and height and refer jquery link.

Comment: Hi Thennarasan , I tried this bit in my code Session("thisContent") = replace(replace(convert_smart_quotes(Upload.form("ifrContent")), "FONT-FAMILY:", "XXXXFONT-FAMILY:"), "FACE=", "XXXXFACE=") but somehow , the page crashes everytime I try to load . Can you all experts help please.

Comment: Session("thisTitle") = convert_smart_quotes(Upload.form("txtTitle"))
    If NOT(validate_string(Session("thisTitle"))) OR NOT(noSpamText(Session("thisTitle"))) then
      Session("thisTitle") = ""
    End If    
    Session("thisSummary") = convert_smart_quotes(Upload.form("txtSummary"))
    If NOT(validate_string(Session("thisSummary"))) OR NOT(noSpamText(Session("thisSummary"))) then
      Session("thisSummary") = ""
    End If
    Session("thisContent")

Comment: I tried using this code but it some how is not working .

Comment: convert_smart_quotes(Upload.form("ifrContent"))    function convert_smart_quotes(ifrContent)
alert(Smart quotes);Content.click(function() {Content.val().replace(/[^\u0000-\u007E]/g, ""));Content.focus()[0].select();});

Comment: anyone ? please help

Comment: @Ritu sorry I was on a vacation. Will be accessing system tomorrow. In the mean time can you please create a fiddle sample with the issue using the fiddle link that I have provided?

Comment: That's no worries Thennarasan . The Problem is fiddle is not working on my system . Can you look at the code above and see . Offcourse I can provide you more details .